# Problem with the config.php file in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have an application on Codeigniter 3 in which some strange anomaly occurs with the config.php file. Periodically, at different times, something either partially overwrites the contents of the file, or completely (the file is empty when opened), and there are times when the contents of the file are overwritten with zeros and ones and it becomes binary. I just can’t understand and track what could be causing the content to be overwritten and why.

The permissions in the config directory are set to 664 for all files. If you set it to 644, then when i open the application an error appears - "Can't open the file".

Has anyone encountered something similar?
How to fix?

Thanks in advance for any help!